# how to select item in QuickPick in test?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm writing a vs code extension, which provide a command, when executing the command, a quick pick list is shown, once user select any item from it, a further action would be executed.

Now I'd like to write a test that covers this scenario, how can I simulate a user's selection after execute the command?

Comment: What languages/frameworks are you using for testing?

Comment: I'm using the autogenerated things, Typescript+assertion.

Here's my repo: https://github.com/anders-liu/vscode-insert-line-number/blob/16d76c99f05bb68a5a348e558ee57dff1d32d6fc/src/test/extension.test.ts#L5

Comment: ok, then you should be able to implement the answer below to simulate the user selecting an option on the command palette

Answer (score 1):

Using JavaScript and Chai/Sinon stubs, it's possible to stub out the vscode command palette functions like this:

```
quickPickStub = mySandBox.stub(vscode.window, 'showQuickPick');
inputBoxStub = mySandBox.stub(vscode.window, 'showInputBox');
```

and then dictate what they return:

```
quickPickStub.resolves({label: 'hello world'});
inputBoxStub.resolves('hello world');
```

AFAIK, it's not possible to simulate a user selecting an item on the tree view.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest checking out the vscode-extension-tester package provided by Red Hat. It can be found at this GitHub repository: https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-extension-tester/wiki/Input#quickpickitem

Using this package, you can resolve your issue by following the code snippet provided in the documentation:

```
import { InputBox } from 'vscode-extension-tester';
const input = InputBox.create();
const picks = await input.getQuickPicks();
await input.selectQuickPick(1);
```